# Anorm parse float values

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

In Play framework 2.0, I'm trying to load a real (i.e. single precision float) type column from PostgreSQL using a row parser like this:

```
case class Foo(bar: Float)

object Foo {
    def all = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
        SQL("SELECT * FROM foo").as(fooParser *)
    }

    val fooParser = {
        get[Float]("bar") map {     
          case bar => Foo(bar)
        }
    }
}
```

This generates an error: `could not find implicit value for parameter extractor: anorm.Column[Float]`

When using double precision types everything works fine. Is it somehow possible to use single precision floats with Anorm?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can always create your own column parser base on the existing ones:

```
 implicit def rowToFloat: Column[Float] = Column.nonNull { (value, meta) =>
  val MetaDataItem(qualified, nullable, clazz) = meta
  value match {
    case d: Float => Right(d)
    case _ => Left(TypeDoesNotMatch("Cannot convert " + value + ":" + value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass + " to Float for column " + qualified))
  }
}
```

but it matches on the type of value returned by the JDBC driver which may not be correct (depends on the column definition).

Comment: check out the code here too: https://github.com/isaka/Play20/commit/27f952257d775e1bfb4a0c61de6e0ef9c5a555d6